# resize images using NicEdit

Tags: javascript, php, html, wysiwyg, nicedit

I am testing and looking for a wysiwyg editor and I found a pretty functional one called nicEdit. Problem is that using firefox all functions are working properly but using chrome, when image is placed, resize option frame doesn't work! How to solve it? If not, any other similar one? Some functions of Tiny MCE are not working  with chrome too. Thank you.

Comment: Please see the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  StackOverflow is for programmers.  If you expect help with this question, you need to post the HTML in question.  We don't care what WYSIWYG editor you used... it is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Chrome doesn't implement such features, so you can opt to write your own version in javascript, or switch to another browser like Firefox or IE.

Answer (score 5):

Use nicEdit and alter code this way in nicEdit.js:

```
var nicImageButton=nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({addPane:function(){this.im=this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag("IMG");this.addForm({"":{type:"title",txt:"Add/Edit Immagine"},width:{type:"text",txt:"Width",style:{width:"150px"}},src:{type:"text",txt:"URL",value:"http://",style:{width:"150px"}},alt:{type:"text",txt:"Alt Text",style:{width:"100px"}},align:{type:"select",txt:"Align",options:{none:"Default",left:"Left",right:"Right"}}},this.im)},submit:function(B){var C=this.inputs.src.value;if(C==""||C=="http://"){alert("You must enter a Image URL to insert");return false}this.removePane();if(!this.im){var A="javascript:nicImTemp();";this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage",A);this.im=this.findElm("IMG","src",A)}if(this.im){this.im.setAttributes({width:this.inputs.width.value,src:this.inputs.src.value,alt:this.inputs.alt.value,align:this.inputs.align.value})}}});nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicImageOptions);
```

you have to add simply

```
,width:{type:"text",txt:"Width",style:{width:"150px"}}
```

and

```
width:this.inputs.width.value,
```

to add the option to insert width parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full code with height edit option, in addition to the width
based on what Yuri Refolo explained

```
var nicImageButton=nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({addPane:function(){this.im=this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag("IMG");this.addForm({"":{type:"title",txt:"Add/Edit Image"},width:{type:"text",txt:"Width",style:{width:"150px"}},height:{type:"text",txt:"Height",style:{width:"150px"}},src:{type:"text",txt:"URL",value:"http://",style:{width:"150px"}},alt:{type:"text",txt:"Alt Text",style:{width:"100px"}},align:{type:"select",txt:"Align",options:{none:"Default",left:"Left",right:"Right"}}},this.im)},submit:function(B){var C=this.inputs.src.value;if(C==""||C=="http://"){alert("You must enter a Image URL to insert");return false}this.removePane();if(!this.im){var A="javascript:nicImTemp();";this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage",A);this.im=this.findElm("IMG","src",A)}if(this.im){this.im.setAttributes({width:this.inputs.width.value,height:this.inputs.height.value,src:this.inputs.src.value,alt:this.inputs.alt.value,align:this.inputs.align.value})}}});nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicImageOptions);
```