# How to resize images in nicEdit in chrome

Tags: resize, editor, wysiwyg, image-resizing, nicedit

i have a problem with nicEdit editor. Simply, i found out that resizing uploaded images does not work in Chrome, in FF yes. I tried this ([resize images using NicEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999461/resize-images-using-nicedit)) but it doesn't work. I didn't find any other advices so i hope someone knows where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and came across this, add this to you nicedit.js:

```
var nicImageButton=nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({addPane:function(){this.im=this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag("IMG");this.addForm({"":{type:"title",txt:"Add/Edit Image"},width:{type:"text",txt:"Width",style:{width:"150px"}},height:{type:"text",txt:"Height",style:{width:"150px"}},src:{type:"text",txt:"URL",value:"http://",style:{width:"150px"}},alt:{type:"text",txt:"Alt Text",style:{width:"100px"}},align:{type:"select",txt:"Align",options:{none:"Default",left:"Left",right:"Right"}}},this.im)},submit:function(B){var C=this.inputs.src.value;if(C==""||C=="http://"){alert("You must enter a Image URL to insert");return false}this.removePane();if(!this.im){var A="javascript:nicImTemp();";this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage",A);this.im=this.findElm("IMG","src",A)}if(this.im){this.im.setAttributes({width:this.inputs.width.value,height:this.inputs.height.value,src:this.inputs.src.value,alt:this.inputs.alt.value,align:this.inputs.align.value})}}});nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicImageOptions);
```

comment out the original line, dont delete it, just incase something goes wrong. this worked for me anyways...

Comment: is it possible to edit the uploaded image with this,?